# richtextbox text range attributes -- protected, hidden, backcolor, etc -- can i set them without selecting a range?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, richtextbox

i want to be able to protect, hide, and highlight different ranges of text within a richtextbox without actually selecting the text -- which is what you seem to have to do for the `SelectionProtected` and `SelectionBackColor` or w/e properties.

how can i do this programatically?  I looked around in reflection and found the `SetCharFormat` method, but I can't really tell how I'd use it to change the aforementioned properties on a specific range of text instead of the selection.

Comment: What do you mean by "Without actually selecting the text" ?

Comment: Text highlighting in RichTextBox is tricky. You have to define TextRanges before you apply any styles. Once you apply any styles the text positions are sifted. I am not sure what you question is though...